# getline function isn't assigning value to string variable

Tags: c++

I can't seem to figure out why `std::getline()` isn't assigning values to my `fileText` string.

I've tried running with breakpoints, and at each call of `fileText` it is just `""`.

The purpose of the program is to eventually take in a `.txt` file and then replace it with an HTML code format, so I need the `fileText` to at least read the first line of the file (for now) and assign that to the title of the program.

I'm also using an `ifstream` AND an `ofstream` because, for some reason, when I use an `fstream` it says the file isn't able to be read, and my program fails.

I've looked at a few sites about how `getline()` and streams work in C++, but I can't figure out what they're doing differently from me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int agrc, char* argv[])
{
    string fileText;
    ifstream infile("TestFile.txt");
    ofstream outfile ("TestFile.txt");

    getline(infile, fileText);
    cout << fileText << endl;

    outfile << "<!DOCTYPE html>" << endl;
    outfile << "<html>" << endl;
    outfile << "<head>" << endl;
    outfile << "<title>" << fileText << "</title>" << endl;

    while (getline(infile, fileText))
    {
        outfile << "<title>" << fileText << "</title>";
        cout << fileText;
        if (fileText == "--help")
        {
            cout << "Success";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no checks to confirm the file was opened or the call to `getline` was successful. If you don't look for errors, be prepared to look for bugs.

Comment: @user4581301 I did the check, the ofstream is also updating the text file and i had an error check to see if the file existed. I used if (!infile) cout << "error" << endl; and nothing printed

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the same file in two streams, an input-only `ifstream`, and an output-only `ofstream`.  The `ofstream` (if it is successful in opening the file) will wipe out the contents of the file, thus there won't be anything for the input stream to read.

Use a *separate* file for output. Especially since you want to write output *while* reading in the input.

When finished, you can then *replace* the original file with the new file, if needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fileText;
    ifstream infile("TestFile.txt");
    ofstream outfile("NewTestFile.txt");

    getline(infile, fileText);
    cout << fileText << endl;

    outfile << "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
    outfile << "<html>\n";
    outfile << "<head>\n";
    outfile << "<title>" << fileText << "</title>\n";
    outfile << "</head>\n";
    outfile << "<body>\n";

    while (getline(infile, fileText))
    {
        outfile << fileText << "\n";
        cout << fileText << "\n";

        if (fileText == "--help")
        {
            cout << "Success";
        }
    }

    outfile << "</body>\n";
    outfile << "</html>\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't know ofstream would overwrite the ifstream, at least not in this context

Comment: @FlawlessCanada you would have if you had read its documentation, for instance https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream, and in particular https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream (default mode is `ios_base::out`), https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode (what `ios_base::out` means), and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open (that `ios_base::out` by itself *destroys* a file's content)